# Is there a way to use Array.splice in javascript with the third parameter as an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I'm attempting the following:

```
var a1 = ['a', 'e', 'f'];  // [a, e, f]
var a2 = ['b', 'c', 'd'];  // [b, c, d]
a1.splice(1, 0, a2);       // expected [a, b, c, d, e, f]
                           // actual (a, [b, c, d], e, f]
```

I am confined in my use case by having a2 exist as an array of indeterminant size.  Does anyone know of a way to feed splice an array as the substitution, or alternatively a built-in function to do this?  I know I could iterate over the elements of a2 and splice them in one at a time, but I'd prefer the fastest method possible because I will need to do this a lot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Array.splice` supports multiple arguments after the first two.  Those arguments will all be added to the array.  Knowing this, you can use `Function.apply` to pass the array as the arguments list.

```
var a1 = ['a', 'e', 'f'];
var a2 = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

// You need to append `[1,0]` so that the 1st 2 arguments to splice are sent
Array.prototype.splice.apply(a1, [1,0].concat(a2));
```

Answer (score 23):

With ES6, you can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator. It makes it much more concise and readable.

```js
var a1 = ['a', 'e', 'f'];
var a2 = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

a1.splice(1, 0, ...a2);
console.log(a1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var a1 = ['a', 'e', 'f'],
    a2 = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

a1.splice(1, 0, a2);

var flatten = [].concat.apply([], a1); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
var a1 = ['a', 'e', 'f'];
var a2 = ['b', 'c', 'd'];

a1.concat(a2, a1.splice(1,a1.length-1)) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var params = a2.slice(0);
params.unshift(1,0);
a1.splice.apply(a1,params);
```

In the more general case:

```
Array.prototype.splice_multi = function(offset,todelete,insert) {
    var params = insert.slice(0);
    params.unshift(offset,todelete);
    return this.splice.apply(this,params);
};
a1.splice_multi(1,0,a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply( [1,2,3], [2, 0].concat([4,5,6]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private moveElements(source: Array<any>, target: Array<any>) {
    target.push(...source);
    source.splice(0, source.length);
    //or
    [].push.apply(target,source);
    source.splice(0, source.length);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer.